# SDL Mobile and image fields within an RTF

Tags: context-engine

I'm looking at implementing context engine and SDL Mobile in a new build.

I see the simplicity of serving the correct image file per device should I have an image from a component imagefield, but if a user embeds a large image file in the middle of an RTF, this is going to be difficult to display.

How have people so far handled this scenario?  My leading thought so far is to do some template magic to wrap the image tag with some context tags.

Comment: Are you trying to deliver the images re-sized using Contextual Image Delivery?

Comment: Who or what should control the image resizing logic (authors, template code, or the application)? And do you have any image path naming requirements?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - yes, we're hoping to use SDL's tools here.

Comment: @AlvinReyes - When an image is entered, it is entered in it's high res state, the CMS functionality handles the rest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

John - your approach for doing some template magic sounds the right direction.   You can replace the image URL with something like

```
<img src="/cid/scale/<context:Eval runat="server" Expression="ui.thumbnailSize"/>/source/images/snow.png" />
```

Where **ui.thumbnailSize** is defined in the context vocabulary as an expression e.g. define

```
 <aspect name="ui">
   <properties>
     <property name="thumbnailSize" type="Integer" 
       expression="if ( browser.displayWidth lt 640 ) { 50  } else { 100 }"/>
```

in cwd_engine_vocabulary_conf.xml.  Then in cwd_engine_conf.xml define where the source **images** points to, e.g.

```
<image>
  <sources>
    <urls>
      <images>http://localhost/images</images>
    </urls>
  </sources>
</image>
```

Comment: thanks @ian - just wanted to validate with this community first.